# Java Versions and Compatibility

Tags: java, java-8, version

I am confused about different versions.

I am a beginner, so forgive me if this is obvious, but...
I am using JDK 20, which I see has some features in testing.  On a separate computer, to test JAR files, I googled and downloaded the most recent version of Java, version 8u361, but not the JDK.  This appears to be what someone who was not a developer would download.

My exported JAR files will not open and say that they were made using a more recent version.  I was able to solve this problem by scaling back and using JDK 1.8, which allows java 8u361 to open them.
Am I misunderstanding something.  The most recent version of Java SE can't run anything that I make with JDK 17, 18, 19 or 20?  I looked at a compatibility chart and couldn't reconcile this questions.
What is the JDK to Java SE equivalence?

Comment: “I looked at a compatibility chart” What chart? Provide a link.

Comment: “downloaded the most recent version of Java” What exactly did you download? From where?

Comment: Post those details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "I googled and downloaded the most recent version of Java, version 8u361"

That is NOT the most recent version of Java. You presumably looked at https://java.com/en which is entitled "Get Java for desktop applications".  Look here instead: https://oracle.com/au/java/technologies/downloads.

Since Java 9, Oracle's position is that it is the developer's responsibility<sup>1</sup> to provide the JRE or JDK for running any desktop applications that they develop and distribute. See Oracle’s white paper, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf), 2020-05.

So you won't find Oracle or OpenJDK badged JREs for Java after Java 8.  For post-Java 8, your options are:

- Instruct your users on how to install an Oracle or OpenJDK JDK.
- Instruct your users on how to install a 3rd-party JRE.
- Use a 3rd-party installer generator to create an installer with an embedded JRE (obtained from a 3rd party) or JDK.
- Use `jlink` to create a custom JRE for your application.
- For Java 14 and later, use `jpackage` to create a native executable for your application.

But to answer your question Java SE 8 (aka JDK 1.8<sup>2</sup>) is 8uxxx, Java SE 9 is 9uxxx, Java SE 10 is 10uxxx and so on. There is no mystery to the compatibility / equivalency.

---

<sup>1 - Oracle don't want to (unfairly) cop the blame for out-of-date / insecure Java installations dropped by application installers.  And the don't want to (unfairly) cop the blame when an official Java patch release installed by the user causes an application to stop working.  Dealing with these things is now 100% *your* responsibility as the app developer / distributor.

2 - The Java 1.N versus Java N stuff is engineering vs marketing nonsense that started back in the early 2000's.  Don't be fooled.  And for more information about Java versions, see the Wikipedia [Java Version History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) page.)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

- Java 21 is current now in 2024-01.
- Java 20 is the latest and greatest version of Java, as of 2023-04.

Versions 8, 11, 17, & 21 are designated as *long-term support* version. These versions continue to see updates over many years. The other versions in-between receive updates only for several months.

An app compiled for a lower numbered version of Java can be run on the same or higher numbered version of Java. (Unless using a feature later removed, a rare occurrence with Java.)

So yes, an app built for Java 8 can run on Java versions 8, 9, … 17, 18, 19, and 20. But not the other way round. An app built for Java 18 can only be run on Java versions 18, 19, and 20.

You can get a JDK (an implementation of the Java specifications) from any of several vendors. These vendors include, in no particular order: Amazon, Adoptium (the Eclipse Foundation), SAP, BellSoft, Microsoft, Azul Systems, Oracle, Red Hat, IBM, and more.

You said:

> JDK 20, which I see has some features in testing

Any feature available by default in Java 20 (or any version) is **entirely ready for production** use. Each release from any of the JDK vendors has gone through extensive testing.

Any feature *not* ready for production, that is, still in development, is marked as either *incubating* or *preview*. These features are **never available to you by default**. So you cannot use them unwittingly. You have to go out of your way to activate such features.

So understand:

- Every new release of every JDK version is fully ready for production use.
- Java 20 is fully ready for production use.

You said:

> What is the JDK to Java SE equivalence?

*Java SE* is [a set of specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) published by Oracle Corp.

*Java* (and *Java SE*) is a trademark owned by Oracle Corp. Available for use only with permission by Oracle.

A JDK is an implementation of the Java specs, plus a compiler and other tools for development and administration.

Some JDK products use the trademark “Java”, but only if permitted by Oracle.

*OpenJDK* is an open-source project developing a codebase for implementing Java across several chip architectures and operating systems. Many companies and individuals contribute. These include Oracle, IBM, Apple, and others. Many JDK products are based largely, if not entirely, on the OpenJDK codebase.